# Updating one field in HDF File

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I can't seem to get this to work. All the examples and threads all have people creating new datasets. I just want to update one field in a dataset that is already created.

Here is what I have:

```
h5_file = h5py.File(event_file_path, "r+") #this works

event_processing_status = int(h5_file[PATH][STATUS].value[0]['Status']) #this works
print({"{0:b}".format(event_processing_status)) #this works
event_processing_status = (event_processing_status | STATUS_UPDATE) #this works
h5_file[PATH][STATUS].value[0]['Status'] = event_processing_status #updating???, no error
event_processing_status = int(h5_file[PATH][STATUS].value[0]['Status']) #this works
print({"{0:b}".format(event_processing_status)) #not the update value

h5_file.close()
```

What am I doing wrong?

More info:
The dtypes of the columns of the dataset:

```
dset = h5_file[PATH][STATUS] 
print(dset.dtype) gives:
[('Status', '<u8'), ('Segments', '<u4'), ('Characterized', '<u4'), ('More_Segments', '<u4'), ('ID', '<i4'), ('Releases', '<u2'), ('Type', '|u1'), ('Track', '<i4')]

dset[0,'Status'] = event_processing_status gives:
TypeError: Field name selections are not allowed for write.
```

Comment: in this line `h5_file[PATH][STATUS].value[0]['Status']) = event_processing_status` there is an extra ) left-side of the assignment. is it really there? or is it a typo?

Comment: copy and paste typo, sorry

Comment: Try changing the indexing order, `[Status'][0]`.  I assume `Status` is a structured array field name.  `h5py`lets you combined record number and ield name into one statement: `dset[0, 'Status'] = status`.  http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html#reading-writing-data.  If my guess doesn't help, show us the `dtype` of this dataset.

Comment: ['Status'][0] didn't work. The dtype is uint64. I also tried h5_file[PATH][STATUS]['Status'] = event_processing_status but got "TypeError: Field name selections are not allowed for write.

Comment: Give us more information about the structure of this dataset.

Comment: gave some more info in the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I had to do:

```
h5_file = h5py.File(event_file_path, "r+") #this works

#Retrieve the dataset containing Event_Status
data= h5_file[PATH][STATUS]

#Get the Event_Status (np.array)
event_status = data['Event_Status']

#Update the value of Event_Status
event_status[0] = np.bitwise_or(event_status[0],np.uint64(STATUS_UPDATE))

#Write updated value to file
elements = data[0]
elements['Event_Status'] = event_status
data[0] = elements

h5_file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Following up on my comment, assuming that your dataset is a structured/compound dtype

```
In [144]: f = h5py.File('test.h5','w')
In [145]: arr = np.ones((3,), dtype='i,f')  # structured array
In [146]: arr
Out[146]: 
array([(1,  1.), (1,  1.), (1,  1.)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f4')])
```

create dataset with data

```
In [147]: ds = f.create_dataset('arr',data=arr)
In [148]: ds
Out[148]: <HDF5 dataset "arr": shape (3,), type "|V8">
In [149]: ds.value
Out[149]: 
array([(1,  1.), (1,  1.), (1,  1.)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f4')])
```

I can index it with record id and field name; this doesn't work for `ds.value` or for `arr`.

```
In [151]: ds[0,'f0']
Out[151]: 1
In [152]: ds[0,'f0'] = 2    # and I can assign values
In [153]: ds.value
Out[153]: 
array([(2,  1.), (1,  1.), (1,  1.)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f4')])
```

I can index with separate record and field entries; but can't change values this way:

```
In [154]: ds[0]['f1']
Out[154]: 1.0
In [155]: ds[0]['f1'] = 234
In [156]: ds.value
Out[156]: 
array([(2,  1.), (1,  1.), (1,  1.)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f4')])
In [157]: ds['f1'][0] = 234
In [158]: ds.value
Out[158]: 
array([(2,  1.), (1,  1.), (1,  1.)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f4')])
```

Assignment requires the combined indexing

```
In [159]: ds[0,'f1'] = 234
In [160]: ds.value
Out[160]: 
array([(2,  234.), (1,    1.), (1,    1.)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f4')])
```

Comment: Tried your assignment definition but it didn't work. I updated the original post with more information

Comment: @lr100, your `dset`dtype works for me.  What is your `h5py` version number?  Mine is `2.6.0`.

Comment: The solution I'm suggesting was new with 2.2, http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/whatsnew/2.2.html#field-indexing-is-now-allowed-when-writing-to-a-dataset-issue-42  I don't know what's possible with older versions.